# setting JAVA_HOME for Maven ONLY regardless of my code java

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, java-6, java-home

I am running different java projects. Understanding that changing java_home system environment each time I switch between them is a bad idea, I'm starting to set JAVA_HOME specifically for each one of them **independently**.
When I set **JAVA_HOME** for maven (version 2) runtime (the java maven uses to run, being a java application)?
To my understanding, JAVA_HOME for maven should not affect how my code is compiled and run (which are supposed to be configured using **maven-compiler-plugin** source and target). Right?

When I set JAVA_HOME in **mvn.bat**:

```
@REM Maven2 Start Up Batch script
set JAVA_HOME=C:\dev\tools\jdk-1.6
```

And my maven-compiler-plugin is configured this way:

```
<plugin>
  <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
  <configuration>
    <source>1.7</source>
    <target>1.7</target>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

I receive this error:

```
[ERROR] BUILD ERROR
[INFO] --------------------------------------
[INFO] Fatal error compiling
Embedded error: invalid target release: 1.7
```

Why does JAVA_HOME specified for maven runtime affect my code compilation? How to separate between the two?

Comment: .... First you tell your machine to use JDK6, and then you compile against Java 7, and you assume this won't cause issues?

Comment: What's the reason of running Maven on Java 6?

Comment: @Stultuske is right ... Change the source and target for `maven-compiler-plugin`to 1.6

Comment: I am assuming that I am telling --MAVEN-- to run with jdk6. not to compile my code with jdk6 (but with 1.7 as specified in source). is that wrong?

Comment: @MoneerOmar you are trying to compile it with 1.7 using the 1.6 JDK.

Comment: Does not <source>1.7</source> tell maven to download the necessary compiler (compiler with java 7) to compile the sources? why should this interfere with the java maven uses to run itself?

Comment: no, maven **never** downloads a compiler.

Comment: thank you guys. a long story settled now.

Answer (score 0):

Maven will use the JRE specified in `JAVA_HOME`
By default it will use the JDK from the same folder for compiling `.java` files

However you can change it in `maven-compile-plugin` [configuration](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/examples/compile-using-different-jdk.html)

```
<project>
  [...]
  <build>
    [...]
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <verbose>true</verbose>
          <fork>true</fork>
          <executable><!-- path-to-javac --></executable>
          <compilerVersion>1.3</compilerVersion>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
    [...]
  </build>
  [...]
</project>
```